# Multiple images and texts on same line using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am trying to create a PDF file on the fly using some backend data and at the bottom of the file I need to include 2 images and a text: a signature image on the left, company logo in the middle and date (underlined with the word "Date" below the line).

I have searched and managed to do two: image on the left and date on the right but now I am stuck trying to get another image in between!

This is what I currently have (assuming I have already read user's name and test date from DB):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());
    doc.Open();

    // Set path to PDF file and images used in the file
    string sPath = Server.MapPath("PDF");
    string sImagePath = Server.MapPath("assets/Images");

    // Set PDF file name
    string sFileName = "SomeFileNameGenerated" + ".PDF";

    // Open document
    PdfWriter myPDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
    doc.Open();

    // Set some font styles
    BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
    Font fntDate = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12f, Font.NORMAL | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);
    Font fntUserName = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 24f, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);

    // Add header image
    iTextSharp.text.Image imgHeader = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sImagePath + "/headerImage.png");
    doc.Add(imgHeader);

    iTextSharp.text.Image imgSignature = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sImagePath + "/Signature.png");

    // Add user's name, underlined, in the center
    Paragraph pUserName = new Paragraph(sUserName, fntUserName);
    pUserName.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    doc.Add(pUserName);

    // Here I am trying to add two images and one date text; 
    // below I have added one image and one text; need to have another image in between
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
    Phrase ph1 = new Phrase();
    Chunk glue = new Chunk(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.VerticalPositionMark());
    Paragraph main = new Paragraph();
    ph1.Add(new Chunk(imgSignature, 0, 0, true)); // Here I add signature image as a chunk into Phrase.    
    ph1.Add(glue); // Here I add special chunk to the same phrase.    
    ph1.Add(new Chunk(sTestDate, fntDate)); // Here I add date as a chunk into same phrase.    
    main.Add(ph1);
    para.Add(main);
    doc.Add(para);
    doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question, but I had much better luck using the html to pdf options from Itext.  Since I was familiar with html it was much easier to lay things out properly.  Much more maintainable for me.

Comment: I would propose using a table instead for such "on the left side this, in the middle that, and this other thing on the right side" tasks.

Comment: @mkl I was thinking of doing the same if all else fails; I thought there might be a more "elegant" way of doing this.

Comment: Well, you might try using tabs but I think using tables will turn out easier. And eventually also more elegant...